# dynamic select dropdown with jquery

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have an insertion form for article which has two select dropdowns. one is for section and another is for subsection.The first select tag is correct.when a user select a section its subsections should be shown.I want to do this job with ajax but nothing happens.I searched and found some examples about this but none of them can resolve my problem.

view

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#subsec').hide();
$('section').change(){
var sec_id=$(this).val();
var url='article_controler/get_options/'+sec_id;
$.ajax({
$('#subsec').show();
url:url,
type:'post',
success:function(resp){
$.each(resp,function(subsec_name)){
var opt=$('<option/>');
opt.val(subsec_name);
opt.text(subsec_name);
$('#subsec').append(opt);
}
})
}

});
</script>
<select id='section'>
<?php foreach($sec->result() as $row) {?>
<option value='<?php echo $row->sec_id ?>'><?php echo $row->sec_name ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<select id='subsec'>
<option value=''></option>
</select>
```

controller

```
function get_options($sec_id){
$data['opt']=$this->article_model->get_options($sec_id);
$this->load->view('insert_art',$data);}
```

model

```
function get_options($sec_id){
$query=$this->db->query('select * from subsection where sec_id='.$sec_id);
return $query;
```

I know there may be many mistakes because it is the first time I am working with jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change url

```
var url=<?php echo base_url(); ?>'article_controler/get_options/'+sec_id;
```

in ajax success

```
success:function(resp){
$('#subsec').html(resp);
}
```

in controller

```
function get_options($sec_id){
 $data['opt']=$this->article_model->get_options($sec_id);
 foreach($data['opt'] as opt){
  echo "<option value=".$opt['sub_sec_id'].">".$opt['sub_sec_name']."</option>";
 }
}
```

in model

```
function get_options($sec_id){
$query=$this->db->query('select * from subsection where sec_id='.$sec_id);
return $query->result_array(); }
```

Comment: it's my pleasure to help you